# Exclude list from search results page but keep the search available within the list view

Tags: search, search-results

Is there any way to exclude certain lists and documentaries from site's OOB search results page only? 
I tried disabling search from the List settings but that makes the list unsearchable within the list view (the small "Find an Item" feature of list view).

I want the users search for items within the list but I do not want the list items appear on the site's search results page (e.g. Pages/results.aspx).

Can we achieve this by any means?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am curious...why?

Comment: The site I am talking about is a publishing site. In the site here are couple of document libraries and lists that is used for some internal purposes only. We do not want them to appear in search results page for the regular user. However, the users who actually use those "internal" libraries like to use the small search feature to quickly locate the items in the list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you should use security. You should either move the documents and lists to a separate site with different security. That way only the users who have access to the site will have permission to see them in search results.